# Jmeter : I am using Json extractor to pass value from the Json response but I am not seeing the value in the debug sampler

Tags: json, jmeter

I am trying to pass the values of the basketId and basketItemId from the Create Basket Json response to Jmeter variable so that I can use these values in the next requests. I set up everything according to the documentation, however I am not able to see the values in the debug sampler in the Tree - Response Data area. Any help is appreciated?
[image: Create Basket]

[image: Json Response]

[image: Json Extractor]

[image: Debug Sampler]
[image: Env variables]

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not seeing your values because your sampler hasn't been executed
2. It has not been executed because you need to provide the same number of the "Default Values" as the variables you declared. If you look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) you will see something like:

   ```
   Mismatch between number of variables, json expressions and default values
   ```

The solution would be adding the default values like:

```
null;null
```

[image]

And assuming your Json Path expression matches something in the response you will see both values.

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)